# After upload an image using (nodejs & multer) the response is sent (to angular) but the image isn't moved to the destination folder

Tags: node.js, angular, multer

I'm a beginner in nodejs and angular, I'm trying to upload image using multer and image is uploaded successfully and send response but i can't find the image in the destination folder no moving happens.

I tried those paths for the folder: ./images
../../images but non of them work here is my hierarchy
[project hierarchy](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18PDMvjZnosXG9wo3-x0CtdyuhjTgFGu6/view)

```
var express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

// SET STORAGE
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:  (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, "./images")
    },
    filename:  (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, file.originalname.toLowerCase())
    }
  })


  router.post('/', upload.single('image'), (req, res, next) => {
    const file = req.file
    if (!file) {
    const error = new Error('Please upload a file')
    error.httpStatusCode = 400
    return next(error)
  }
    res.send(file);

  })
  module.exports = router;
```

I expected to find the uploaded image in the destination folder but the image isn't moved to it

Comment: isn't var upload = multer({ storage: storage }); should be after storage is defined?

Comment: oh how i didn't notice that thanks a lot